# How to get data from a linking table where all data much match and only match?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I need to get only the product_price_id that matches all the ids passed.

Given the following table:

```
id  attribute_id(uuid)                    product_price_id(uuid)
1   004f92e8-34ca-4518-bfea-aef9abf07994  6fdcc85d-6fca-44c8-bb04-7b94bfc57294
2   b2122096-a886-4bab-9a2b-8e237c59460a  0e5bf36f-6e78-474f-a7f5-a77377ccb466
3   004f92e8-34ca-4518-bfea-aef9abf07994  0e5bf36f-6e78-474f-a7f5-a77377ccb466
...
```

I need to bring back the product_price_id where the attribute_id matches.  There should only be one value returned or if not found return null.

If the where clause only has `004f92e8-34ca-4518-bfea-aef9abf07994` for attribute_id I need to bring back only `6fdcc85d-6fca-44c8-bb04-7b94bfc57294` and not `0e5bf36f-6e78-474f-a7f5-a77377ccb466`

If my where clause has `004f92e8-34ca-4518-bfea-aef9abf07994` and `b2122096-a886-4bab-9a2b-8e237c59460a` for attribute_id I need to bring back `0e5bf36f-6e78-474f-a7f5-a77377ccb466`

This can be n number of combos and not just 1 or two passed every time.

I have tried:

```
SELECT product_price_id
FROM product_override_pricing t
WHERE t.attribute_id IN ('004f92e8-34ca-4518-bfea-aef9abf07994', 'b2122096-a886-4bab-9a2b-8e237c59460a')
GROUP BY product_price_id
HAVING COUNT(1) = 2;
```

Which seems to work if I pass 2 values in the where clause.

But, when I pass one value I get 2 results:

```
SELECT product_price_id
FROM product_override_pricing t
WHERE t.attribute_id IN ('004f92e8-34ca-4518-bfea-aef9abf07994')
GROUP BY product_price_id, attribute_id
HAVING COUNT(1) = 1;
```

I tried something like this just for testing purposes

```
SELECT * FROM product_override_pricing as s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (( SELECT '004f92e8-34ca-4518-bfea-aef9abf07994' UNION SELECT 'b2122096-a886-4bab-9a2b-8e237c59460a' )
EXCEPT
 (SELECT sp.product_price_id FROM product_override_pricing sp WHERE sp.product_price_id = s.product_price_id ) );
```

But, I have received the following error:
`EXCEPT types text and uuid cannot be matched`

Comment: (Imagine how much typing you would have saved if you had chosen for this example a key like '34' instead of '6fdcc85d-6fca-44c8-bb04-7b94bfc57294')

Comment: I am using postgres.  That is why this question is tagged with postgresql. Also, uuid and ints or numeric should be irrelevant for this example.

Comment: I ended using the following query suggested by @Tim Biegeleisen:
`SELECT product_price_id
FROM product_override_pricing
GROUP BY product_price_id
HAVING
    COUNT(CASE WHEN attribute_id NOT IN (uuid1, uuid2, uuid3) THEN 1 END) = 0 AND
    COUNT(DISTINCT attribute_id) = 3;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a general query which should work here:

```
SELECT product_price_id
FROM product_override_pricing
GROUP BY product_price_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN attribute_id <> '004f92e8-34ca-4518-bfea-aef9abf07994'
                  THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

### Demo

The idea here is to aggregate by the `product_price_id`, and then assert that only the `004f92e8-34ca-4518-bfea-aef9abf07994` UUID `attribute_id` is associated with the matching products.

A more general form of the query:

```
SELECT product_price_id
FROM product_override_pricing
GROUP BY product_price_id
HAVING
    COUNT(CASE WHEN attribute_id NOT IN (uuid1, uuid2, uuid3) THEN 1 END) = 0 AND
    COUNT(DISTINCT attribute_id) = 3;
```

The first part of the `HAVING` clause asserts that no UUID other than the 3 in the whitelist are associated with the product.  The second part asserts that in fact all three in the whitelist appear.

Comment: I tried your query above and both `product_price_id`s are getting return.
`0e5bf36f-6e78-474f-a7f5-a77377ccb466` and `6fdcc85d-6fca-44c8-bb04-7b94bfc57294`

Comment: What is "that?"  My code?  Your code?  I think my answer should be working for you.

Comment: I tried your code.  Sorry.

`SELECT product_price_id
FROM product_override_pricing
WHERE attribute_id IN ('004f92e8-34ca-4518-bfea-aef9abf07994') 
GROUP BY product_price_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT attribute_id) = 1; `

And my results are:
product_price_id
"0e5bf36f-6e78-474f-a7f5-a77377ccb466"
"6fdcc85d-6fca-44c8-bb04-7b94bfc57294"

I should only get back `6fdcc85d-6fca-44c8-bb04-7b94bfc57294`

Comment: @DrewBomb Sorry, I misread your question.  Try my updated answer, which at least works for the example you gave above.

Comment: Thank you.  That works.  Now, what about passing more than 1 attribute_id?  For example:
`b2122096-a886-4bab-9a2b-8e237c59460a` and `004f92e8-34ca-4518-bfea-aef9abf07994` should return `0e5bf36f-6e78-474f-a7f5-a77377ccb466`

Comment: `SELECT product_price_id
FROM product_override_pricing
GROUP BY product_price_id
HAVING
    COUNT(CASE WHEN attribute_id NOT IN (uuid1, uuid2, uuid3) THEN 1 END) = 0 AND
    COUNT(DISTINCT attribute_id) = 3;`

Worked.  Thanks!